# Batch file ignores ELSE statement inside a FOR loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

I am currently creating a batch file that decompresses all the archives that it will detect in a specified folder. Right now I am trying to detect archive files within the specified folder using this code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

SET quote="
SET cwdText=Current working directory: 
SET cwd=%cd%
SET fullCWD=%cwdText%%cwd%
SET path=%~dp0
SET types=file_types.txt
SET fullPath=%path%%types%

ECHO %fullCWD%
ECHO %fullPath%

:SPECIFYPATH
ECHO:
SET /P directory=Specify the full path location of the archive files:

IF "%cd%"=="%directory%" (
ECHO Specified location is already the current directory 
GOTO SPECIFYPATH
) ELSE (
PUSHD %directory%
CD
GOTO CHECKARCHIVES
)

:CHECKARCHIVES
FOR %%T IN (*.zip,*.rar,*.7z) DO (
IF EXIST %%T (
    ECHO Archive files detected
    GOTO EOF
) ELSE (
    ECHO Archive files not detected
    GOTO EOF
)
GOTO EOF
)

:EXTRACT
ECHO Extracting archive files

:EOF
PAUSE
```

The part wherein I start checking for archive files is at the `:CHECKARCHIVES` label. The problem I'm having right now is that whenever I try to specify a folder wherein there are no archive files, the code immediately jumps to the `:EXTRACT` label and does not go to the `ELSE` statement inside the `FOR` statement. Can someone explain why is that so?

I also tried using `IF NOT EXIST...` statement just after the first `IF` statement but I still get the same behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the element that is being enumerated by the `for` command doesn't contain a wildcard, the code in the `do` clause is executed and the `for` replaceable parameter will contain the element as is.

But when the element being enumerated contains a wildcard it is assumed that it needs to be expanded and the file system is checked for presence of files matching the wildcard expression. If there are not files matching, the code in the `do` clause will not be executed for this element. If there are files matching the expression, the code in the `do` clause will be executed not for the expression, but for each matching file, and the `for` replaceable parameter will hold a reference to the current one.

As your code is using wildcards if there are matching files, the code in the `do` clause is executed for each of the files (in your case only for the first file found because the `goto`), and, if there are not any matching file, the code in the `do` clause is not executed so the `else` clause can not be reached.

But, lets suppose that the `for` will not check the file system, and the elements indicated are iterated as written. You will have a logic error. The inner `if` command will check the existence of files matching only the first set. If not files matching the first set are found, you are leaving the `for` command with the `goto` inside the `else` clause, so, the rest of the sets are not checked.

To keep the `for` to check for existence of files a better way could be

```dos
for %%T in (*.zip, *.rar, *.7z) do goto :extract
echo No archives found
goto eof
```

If any file, matching any of the wildcard expressions, is found then the `goto` will cancel the current enumeration and jump to your `:extract` label. If the `for` loop ends and the next line is reached it is because no matching file has been found.

Comment: I see. So it means that the `FOR` statement in batch file environment behaves more like an iterative version of an `IF` statement and not like what we usually know in programming languages like C++ and the like?

Comment: I'd not say iterative `if`; you can consider it as something like `for each`, iterating through all matching files...

Comment: @Jairo, `for` just [*"globs"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) the elements in the indicated set.

Answer (score 1):

That is the correct behavior for the code you have shown. If there are no archive file you will not enter the 'DO' construct. You could do something like this, or better yet zero a counter before entering the loop and increment it in the loop... then interrogate it outside the loop if you want a count of files.

```
SET "Msg=Archive files not detected"
FOR %%T IN (*.zip,*.rar,*.7z) DO (
    SET "Msg=Archive files detected"
    REM do something else as needed
)
ECHO %Msg%
```

Comment: Isn't the line `SET "Msg=Archive files not detected"` useless without using an `IF` statement that will trigger it and the `FOR` loop statement? I'm sorry if I'm asking this. This is my first time to develop a batch file.

Another problem that I have thought of if I use my code and what you suggested is the possibility that I may add other archive file types aside from ZIP, RAR and 7z. Is there a way for me to do this? I was thinking of using a text file wherein all the archive file types are enumerated there and use that file to check whether any of them are present in the directory/folder.

Comment: 1. no, it's not useless, it preinitialises `Msg`; in case archive files are encountered, the `for` koop is iterating and `Msg` is updated/overwritten; 2. concerning list of archive types: it's not a great idea to extend the scope of your original question by comments; instead you should post a new question covering that...

Comment: @aschipfl I understand. I will post a new question with regards to my other concern.

Answer (score 0):

In addition of RGuggisberg's post, you could check file like this with different syntax always outside the `for-loop`.

```vb
for %%t in (*.zip,*.rar,*.7z) do set "myvar=%%t"
if defined myvar ( echo msg#1 Archive files DETECTED ) else ( echo msg#1 Archive files NOT detected )

for %%t in (*.zip,*.rar,*.7z) do (
  set "myvar=%%t"
)
if defined myvar ( echo msg#2 Archive files DETECTED ) else ( echo msg#2 Archive files NOT detected )

rem check the myvar by negation
if NOT defined myvar ( echo msg#3 Archive files NOT detected ) else ( echo msg#3 Archive files DETECTED )
```